# What's the best way to write facebook apps in haskell?

Tags: facebook, haskell, yesod

I'm building a site in haskell and the yesod web framework as a side project, and what I'd like to do is create a facebook app that lets users search their wall and the wall of their friends and groups.

I've considered using the JavaScript SDK, cbut most of the work will happen behind the scenes in a helper function called from the postSearhR helper function, so that won't work.

Searching google for the phrase 'haskell "build facebook app"' and variants doesn't turn anything up, and a glance at hackage shows a package called happstack-facebok at version 0.30 with nothing in the way of haddock documentation. Searching SO with the haskell and facebook tags doesn't return anything useful either.

Does anyone know of an example I can use?

Comment: @Polynomial http://www.haskellers.com/ https://github.com/snoyberg/haskellers

Comment: https://github.com/Saizan/fbspider is a simple 'spider'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

happstack-facebook is obsolete now anyway. Facebook changed their API significantly, for the better. (Not saying it is great... just better than before).

A good starting point now might be the authenticate library. in Web.Authenticate.Facebook:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/authenticate/0.10.4/doc/html/Web-Authenticate-Facebook.html

there is a function, getGraphData. That should at least get you to the point of being able to access some of the facebook API.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Not sure what else is needed.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.